# Load bootstrap modal on page load using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootbox

I am using bootbox.js plugin to show popup but there is one condition where i want to show the modal popup on pageoad event using c#. If i use window.load() event in javascript the modal popup showsup but not throught padgeload method.

I am calling the script using scriptManager,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        uname = (string)Session["username"];
        if (uname != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "teste", "teste();", true);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function teste() {
        event.preventDefault();
        bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function () {
        });
    }
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "setTimeout(function(){teste();}, 2000);", true);

try using it as i have set 2 sec delay so that page get load properly before you call the function let me know if its work

Comment: No it is not working..

Comment: I know it's not an answer but... This should NOT be done at all.

Comment: Then whats the solution! @tocquevile

Comment: I would assume RegisterStartupScript doesn't work because the WebForms engine injects this code before jQuery et al are loaded into the page. Your best bet would be to move jQuery, Bootstrap.js, etc. to the head of your page, although that's normally not recommended.